# Preventing form submit doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to prevent form submit if the input is empty. The code looks something like this:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form#input_form", function(e){
  if(!$(this).find("input[type=text]").val()){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

This doesn't work. The request just goes through even though it executes both preventDefault and stopPropagation.

However, if I do the following it successfully prevents submit:

```
$("form#input_form").on("submit", function(e){
  if(!$(this).find("input[type=text]").val()){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

I don't understand what the difference is, it's basically the same thing except that the former attaches the handler at document level whereas the latter does it to the form itself. By the way, I'm using `form_for` helper to render the form.

Comment: for me both the code snippets worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to validate your user's input. Example shown below:

```
var userInputVal = $(this).find("input[type=text]").val();

// validate the user input. no error if user entered data with one or more characters.
function validateUserInput() {
    var n = /(\.){1,}/; // creates a regular expression object pattern.
    if (n.test(userInputVal)) {  
        userInputError.hide(); // hide the error message if the user input is one or more characters
        return true;
    } else {
        userInputError.show(); // show the error message if the user input is one or more characters
        return false;
    }
}
```