# How to validate a single field with Hibernate Validator?

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, hibernate-validator

I'm looking for a way to validate a single field at a time. This is so, while a user is filling in a form, each time the keypress or blur event occurs for each field, i can validate that field individually and show / hide its error message.

Is that possible? If so, how can I do it? Some google searching hasn't turned up any results which validate a single field, rather than the whole form.

Comment: @BheshGurung It is a web application but I'm using Google Web Toolkit, so validation is actually being done via hibernate validator..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `javax.validation.Validator#validateProperty()` for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry i came too late. I am using Hibernate and i tried using this to validate a String parameter value, but it didn't work either. Could you take a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767164/spring-mvc-with-hibernate-validator-to-validate-single-basic-type) ? I would appreciate it. Regards!

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend that you try using Javascript [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to validate user inputs and show/hide error messages.
I provided a code implementation example in the post at this link: [Example using Regular Expresssions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960958/preventing-form-submit-doesnt-work/21961134#21961134)

Add an event listener to relevant input field in the DOM to provide responsiveness.

```
var letterField = document.getElementById('letterField'); // DOM element containing user input 
letterField.addEventListener('keyup', function() { // key press event listener using anonymous function
    if (event.keyCode === 13) { // run this code if the 'enter' key is pressed
        if ( ... ) { 
            ...
        };
    };
};
```

If you want to add effects, include the following code to transition the error message. Refer to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for other effects:

```
userInputError.delay(800).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Google Web Toolkit which compiles java to javascript, so actually I'm looking for a way to do this via hibernate.. any ideas?

Comment: It seems I've bitten off more than I can chew in answering this post. All is not lost though. Thanks to you I've discovered a new world in GWT, and meanwhile it appears someone else has come up with a valid solution to the actual problem.

Comment: GWT is great. I highly recommend it. There's a #GWT channel on freenode if you need help.